# Problema con FormArray que contiene un FormGroup

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Hola a todos tengo un problema a la hora de insertar los datos que recojo de un servicio rest, este servicio seria asi.

```
valor: Object =
{
nombre: "jose",
apellido: "campos",
direccion: {
  direccion: "calle de la mar",
  numero: "18"
},

contactos: [
  {
    numero: "123454444",
    tipo: "fijo"
  },
  {
    numero: "44455533",
    tipo: "fijo"
  }
]
```

}

Monto el formulario de la siguiente manera.

```
   this.forma = new FormGroup({
  'nombre': new FormControl(''),
  'apellido': new FormControl(''),
  'direccion': new FormGroup({
    'direccion': new FormControl(''),
    'numero': new FormControl('')
     }),
    'contactos': new FormArray([
         new FormControl(''),
         new FormControl('')
               ]),
```

});

Aqui es donde muestro el FormArray "contactos" que tiene dentro un formGroup

```
 <div formArrayName="contactos">
<div *ngFor="let item of forma.controls['contactos'].controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Numero</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Numero" formControlName="numero">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Tipo</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tipo" formControlName="tipo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Todo carga bien excepto "contactos" , si hago un console.log de contactos o incluso si hago submit, los dato estan cargados, pero no consigo que se me reflejen en el input del formulario

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'contactos -> 0 -> numero'
```

este es el error que me tira , deduzco que es por que no encuetra el formControl "numero" pero es que no veo donde ponerlo ya que si utilizo

```
  'contactos': new FormArray([

        new FormGroup({
           'numero':  new FormControl(''),
             'tipo': new FormControl('')
        })
         ]),
```

No puedo ni cargar el formulario, alguien puede echarme una mano llevo ya varios dias y no veo la solucion.

Answer (score 1):

no sé lo que intentáis hacer pero creo que lo habéis complicado un poco.

El error te da porque 'contactos' no es un Control de la variable "forma". 'contactos' es un formArray como defenís en:

```
 this.forma = new FormGroup({
  'nombre': new FormControl(''),
  'apellido': new FormControl(''),
  'direccion': new FormGroup({
    'direccion': new FormControl(''),
    'numero': new FormControl('')
     }),
    'contactos': new **FormArray**([
         new FormControl(''),
         new FormControl('')
               ]),
```

Lo que quiere decir que no podéis buscarlo en el HTML dentro del array de controls de 'forma':

```
<div *ngFor="let item of forma.controls['contactos'].controls;
```

Lo que si que podéis buscar dentro de forma.controls son a los hijos de contactos si le dierais un nombre:

```
'contactos': new **FormArray**([
         'fijo1': new FormControl(''),
         'fijo2' new FormControl('')
               ]),
```

Después podríais referenciarlos, así:

```
 forma.controls['fijo1']
```

Si lo queréis hacer de forma dinámica tenéis que hacer un formGroup nuevo para contactos:

```
this.forma = new FormGroup({
  'nombre': new FormControl(''),
  'apellido': new FormControl(''),
  'direccion': new FormGroup({
    'direccion': new FormControl(''),
    'numero': new FormControl('')
     })}

this.formaContactos= new FormGroup
  ([
         'fijo1': new FormControl(''),
         'fijo2': new FormControl('')
               ]),
```

y en el HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of formaContactos.controls ....
```

Comment: Ok gracias probare la forma dinamica, ya que no me deja poner un indice a los controls del array `'contactos': new **FormArray**([
         'fijo1': new FormControl(''),
         'fijo2' new FormControl('')
               ]),  `